# Java wildcard in multi-level generic type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Why `Bar.go` is `OK` with argument `f2` but not with argument `f1`?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<Foo<?>> f1 = new Foo<Foo<?>>();
        Foo<Foo<String>> f2 = new Foo<Foo<String>>();
        Bar.go(f1);     // not OK
        Bar.go(f2);     // OK
    }

    public static void p(Object o) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}

class Foo<E> {
}

class Bar {
    public static <T> void go(Foo<Foo<T>> f) {
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler automatically infer type `T` as `capture of ?` in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

(In the following comments, w.r.t. a class generic in `E` like `Foo< E >`, define "covariant method" as a method that returns an `E` without having any parameters using `E`, and a "contravariant method" as the opposite: one which takes a formal parameter of type `E` but doesn't return a type involving `E`.  [The real definition of these terms is more complicated, but never mind that for now.])

It seems that the compiler is trying to bind `T` to `Object` in the case of `f1`, because if you do

```
class Bar0 {
    public static < T > void go( Foo< Foo< ? extends T > > f ) {
        // can pass a Foo< T > to a contravariant method of f;
        // can use any result r of any covariant method of f,
        // but can't pass T to any contravariant method of r
    }
}
```

then the `go(f1)` works, but now `go(f2)` doesn't, because even though `Foo< String > <: Foo< ? extends String >`, that does not imply that `Foo< Foo< String > > <: Foo< Foo< ? extends String > >`.

Here are a few modifications that compile for both `f1` and `f2`:

```
class Bar1 {
    public static < T > void go( Foo< ? super Foo< T > > f ) {
        // can't properly type the results of any covariant method of f,
        // but we can pass a Foo< T > to any contravariant method of f
    }
}

class Bar2 {
    public static < T > void go( Foo< ? extends Foo< ? extends T > > f ) {
        // can't pass a Foo< T > to a contravariant method of f;
        // can use result r of any covariant method of f;
        // can't pass a T to a contravariant method of r;
        // can use result of covariant method of r
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the case of `Foo<Foo<?>>`? If I need to work in terms of `Foo<?>` I can write `Foo<? extends Foo<?>>` but I feel it to bring more variance that I actually would intend if I were able to use `Foo<Foo<?>>`. How accepting of `Foo<String>` as `Foo<?>` is called in terms of variance?

Comment: If I understand your question @ony, it's not accepting of it at all.

`Foo< Foo< String > >` is not a `Foo< Foo< ? > >`.  In general, `G< S >` is not a `G< T >` even if `S` is a `T`, but `G< S >` is a `G< ? extends T >` and `G< T >` is a `G< ? super S >`.

`Foo< ? >` is short for `Foo< ? extends Object >`, so `Foo< String >` is a `Foo< ? >`.  But let `Foo< String >` be `S` and `Foo< ? >` be `T`.  The non-relationship above means `Foo< S >` is not a `Foo< T >`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo<Foo<?>> f1 = new Foo<Foo<?>>();
```

This implies that the type is unknown and objects of any type can be added to `Foo<Foo<?>>` that are heterogeneous and compiler cannot guarantee that all object in `Foo<Foo<?>>` are of same type. Hence it cannot be passed to `Bar.go` that takes a bounded type as parameter.

You can instead declare that as `Foo<Foo<Object>> f1 = new Foo<Foo<Object>>();` to pass it to `Bar.go` where you explicitly mention everything is of type `Object`.

Comment: actually, assuming `Foo` is like a collection, it is your suggested type that is the heterogeneous one.  `Foo<Foo<?>>` means a Foo containing Foos containing some specific, homogeneous element type that is not specified.

Comment: The idea was to drive the point that `Foo<Foo<?>>` works on unbounded type and so the compiler can't match it with a bounded counterpart. And yes, I agree the terminology was more assuming that `Foo` is a container which it need not be, but the point stil holds.

Comment: @JudgeMental: No, `Foo<Foo<?>>` is heterogenous and can contain `Foo<Bar>` and `Foo<Baz>` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

A Nice Read [What do multi-level wildcards mean?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20do%20multilevel%20wildcards%20mean?)

Example:

```
Collection< Pair<String,Long> >        c1 = new ArrayList<Pair<String,Long>>();

Collection< Pair<String,Long> >        c2 = c1;  // fine
Collection< Pair<String,?> >           c3 = c1;  // error
Collection< ? extends Pair<String,?> > c4 = c1; // fine
```

Of course, we can assign a `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>` to a `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>`.  There is nothing surprising here.

But we can not assign a `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>` to a `Collection<Pair<String,?>>`.  The parameterized type `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>` is a homogenous collection of  pairs of a String and a Long ;  the parameterized type `Collection<Pair<String,?>>` is a heterogenous collection of pairs of a String and something of unknown type.  The heterogenous `Collection<Pair<String,?>>` could for instance contain a `Pair<String,Date>` and that clearly does not belong into a `Collection<Pair<String,Long>>`.  For this reason the assignment is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I will  prove that if the compiler allows `Bar.go(f1);`, the type system(safety) would be broken:

Java grammar allows you to use `T` as a type to declare variables in `go()`. Something like: `T t = <something>`.

Now, let's use `ArrayList` instead of `Foo`,

Then we have:

```
class HW {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<?>> f1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>();
        go(f1);     // not OK
    }

    public static <T> void go(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> f) {
    }
}
```

`ArrayList<?>` is supertype of `ArrayList<String>`, it is also supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>`, meaning that you can do the following in `main`:

```
ArrayList<?> s = new ArrayList<String>();
f1.add(s);

ArrayList<?> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();
f1.add(i);
```

Now, let's assume that the compiler allows you to call `go()` with `f1` as argument.
The option to infer `T` are:

1. `T = Object`, but `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>` is not `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` because `ArrayList<Object>` is not the same type as `ArrayList<?>`
   So that is not allowed option.
2. `T = ?`, then we would be able to do:

   ```
   public static <T> void go(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> f) {
        ArrayList<T> alt1 = f.get(0); // ArrayList<String>
        T str = alt1.get(0);
        ArrayList<T> alt2 = f.get(1); // ArrayList<Integer>
        alt2.add(str); // We have added String to List<Integer>
       // ... type system broken
   }
   ```

`go()` to work in both cases you have to do:

```
public static void go(ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<?>> f) {
}
```

Comment: Your proof seems broken. Why should `alt.add(new Integer(1))` (I assume you mean `add`) work? The subtyping between `T` and `Integer` being unknown, it would be rejected. A working proof would be: `f.get(1).add(f.get(0).get(0))`, effectively adding a `String` to a list of `Integer`s.

Comment: @Ben Schulz Thank you for discovering my mistake. Fixed.